# Bulk data import in a java application

Tags: database, hibernate, spring, dbimport

I am on java project to import huge amount of data from .csv file to a database. I am interested in understanding what can be the best approach in achieving this.

- Definitely one of the options is to
  using java application calling stored
  procedure.
- Second option I can think
  of is, since we are already using
  spring, spring-jdbc pair can help us
  too.
- Currently we are using spring-hibernate pair to get this done at a application level (This is something I presume is not a right approach)

Can you please help me with some thought from other end of spectrum?

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use native support of the DB while doing bulk operations with huge data. If Oracle then [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ). If Postgres then they have the [COPY](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2002-05/msg00213.php) command.

If you are looking for Java specific options then below is my preference order

1. JDBC: use [batch operations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm) support but this has a limitation that any failure in the batch operation will short-circuit the entire flow
2. Hibernate: ORMs are not meant for this. However, you can use [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) and [batch configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) together to achieve optimal performance.

Comment: currently we are using postgres database. Is there tools like SqlLoader in postgres database?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion , such cases (bulk import) should be addressed using database features:

In case of Oracle SQLLoader (as suggested by @Pangea)

In case of MS SQL Server BCP (Bulk Copy)

If you are looking @ Java based approach for this then I echo  @Pangea
In addition to to that
You can break down a batch insert into sub-batches and run them concurrently for better perf.

Ex: If you have 10k records to be inserted then you can build batches of 200 records each and insert 5 batches concurrently.

In this case you need code to track each sub-batch.

Hope this helps!